# Is the secondary attack the same as primary?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

Some equipment do not have a secondary attack like the engineers blowtorch, but others looks like there is no difference between primary and secondary attack.

When using knives as Stealth or medkids, ammo boxes or daisycutter as support is there a difference between using primary or secondary attack(right and left mouse button) even though it looks the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no difference between left and right mousebutton for knives, kits or mines.